# iPad/iphone font leading and kerning

Tags: iphone, fonts, styling, kerning

I've searched on the Internet but can't find definite details.

Is there anyway to specify leading and keening for uilabels, textfields or textviews?

I could create custom fonts for each leading and keening pairing but this seems a bit overkill.

Comment: There does not appear to be. CoreText offers solutions tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be. CoreText offers solutions tho.